# Python multiprocessing.pool uses too many resources (processors and/or memory)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am attempting to run a series of simulation sets in parallel (set A, set B,...). The simulation sets have subset variations (subset A1, subset A2,...), and each subset contains 500+ simulations. Currently I am working with 18 sets, and each set only has 1 subset. Realistically, I would like neither number to matter, and any number of sets+subset combinations could be processed. This is all occurring on a Linux machine running Anaconda Python 3.6.3 with `multiprocessing.cpu_count() = 72`.

There seems to be some sort of resource issue occurring. I have not been able to pin down exactly when the resource issue begins, but it is usually after a couple sets have fully completed. In the past, I have run this script with 3-4 sets and there was never a resource issue that was noticeable to me. What will happen is that memory usage increases drastically and it seems the number of processors that are used increases to be larger than what I specify which is `65`. The simulations' CPU usage decreases drastically to less than 20% after it begins as well, and over time, the machine will lock up entirely requiring a forced restart in order to do anything.

My simplified code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess

def getCMDs(ARGS):
    # do stuff
    return subsetCMDs

def minions(cmd):
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
    return

def runParallel(sim_sets):
    with mp.Pool(processes=65) as pool:
        for i in sim_sets:
            subsetCMDs = getCMDs(i)
            for runCMDs in subsetCMDs:
                term_flag = False
                try:
                    pool.map(minions,runCMDs)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    pool.terminate()
                    pool.join()
                    term_flag = True
                    break
            if term_flag:
                break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runParallel(['set A', 'set B', 'set C'])
```

I have tried finding solutions, but I can't seem to find anything similar to my issue as far as I am understanding it. I have read into `maxtasksperchild`, but I am still unsure on whether this would be the correct solution as I believe it may be a too-many-processor issue rather than a too-much-memory-usage issue.

My thoughts could be entirely wrong, but I figured I would share to help with discussion. Thank you for the help!

**Edit:** Firstly, I figured I should provide a little more information about what is happening when the issue occurs. I usually leave `htop` open after I run it initially, and for the first ~6 hours, I see nothing out of the ordinary on `htop`:

1. All 72 processors at various usage amounts
2. ~13/252 GB of Memory used
3. 0/128 GB of Swap used
4. Tasks running: ~67

When I come to check on the script the next day, I see:

1. All 72 processors at 100%
2. 252/252 GB of Memory used
3. 128/128 GB of Swap used
4. Tasks running: 1000+

I also am not sure when throughout the night the issue begins.

After heavy research, I have tried updating my script to use `asyncio` subprocesses shown below, but I am still getting the same results as with `multiprocessing`.

`Asyncio` script:

```
import asyncio

def getCMDs(ARGS):
    # do stuff
    return subsetCMDs

async def execCMD(sem,cmd):
    async with sem:
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd)
        await proc.wait()
    return

async def execAsyncBatch(nCPU,execCMDs):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(nCPU)
    all_future = []
    for cmd in execCMDs:
        coro = execCMD(sem,cmd)
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
        all_futures.append(future)
    await asyncio.gather(*all_futures)
    return

def runParallel(sim_sets,nCPU):
    for i in sim_sets:
        subsetCMDs = getCMDs(i)
        for runCMDs in subsetCMDs:
            term_flag = False
            try:
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                job_future = asyncio.ensure_future(execAsyncBatch(nCPU,runCMDs))
                loop.run_until_complete(job_future)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                term_flag = True
                break
        if term_flag:
            break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reunParallel(['set A', 'set B', 'set C'], 65)
```

I plan on running each set individually with the `multiprocessing` script (as I understand `multiprocessing` much more than `asyncio`) to see if somewhere along the lines I have a bad set, but I figured I would provide an update in the meantime. Thanks again!

Comment: So in this scenario you have 72 processors and create a multiprocessing pool with 65 processes. Next though each of those 65 processes uses subprocess to spawn a new process meaning you are actually spinning up 131 concurrent processes by running this code. Also `multiprocessing.map()` is specifically recommended against for large volume. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map

Comment: @AmosBaker So to ensure I am understanding this correctly, are you saying 65 `mp.pool` processes + 65 `subprocess` processes + 1 process to run python script = 131? What would then be the recommended method to replace the use of subprocess? Also I have used `mp.map()` before in this same script with 1000+ iterables and it handled it fine, so I can't imagine my current use with 500+ iterables to be the problem but that is my thought. What would be considered "very long iterables"?

Comment: This honestly feels like a good use case for [asyncio subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html). If all your Python processes do is start a subprocess and wait for it to return... why even start the Python processes?

Comment: @cmoen "very long iterables" seems like one of those intentionally arbitrary quantities. 
Totally agree with @Dominik that async is the way to go, switching to `map_async()` would require minimal change, but using `asyncio.subprocess` might actually grant you better performance. At the end of the day the best approach might be to implement a few different ways and compare what performance looks like with a reduced subset and then make some assumptions about whether it would scale.

Comment: @AmosDaker @DominikStańczak I have provided an update above with an attempt at using `asyncio` subprocesses and some more information about the issue if it will help you help me. Thanks!